# Activemq high memory consumption

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, activemq-classic, mcollective

I am using ActiveMQ 5.8.0 along with puppet mcollective 2.5.2, Java 1.8.0_31

And I am facing memory issue in AciveMQ. The problem is ActiveMQ is consuming memory and it is not getting free after that. It keeps on increasing until we restart ActiveMQ. I don't know what is the issue with this, might be some configuration missing or garbage collection settings. Below are the config files.

activemq.xml

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--
    The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
-->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true">

    <!--
      For better performances use VM cursor and small memory limit.
      For more information, see:

      http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

      Also, if your producer is "hanging", it's probably due to producer
      flow control.

      For more information, see:
      http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
    -->

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="100mb">
              <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                <vmCursor />
              </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
            </policyEntry>
            <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="100mb" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="300000" >
              <!--
                Use VM cursor for better latency
                For more information, see:

                http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

              <pendingQueuePolicy>
                <vmQueueCursor/>
              </pendingQueuePolicy>
              -->
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>

    <!--
      The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
      JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
      the JVM. For more information, see:

      http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
    -->
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <!--
      Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
      mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
      For more information, see:

      http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
    -->
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    <plugins>
      <!--
        Enable the statisticsBrokerPlugin to allow ActiveMQ to collect
        statistics.
      -->
      <statisticsBrokerPlugin/>

      <!--
        Here we define a default set of users
      -->
      <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
        <users>
          <authenticationUser username="mcollective" password="secret" groups="mcollective,admins,everyone"/>
        </users>
      </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
      <authorizationPlugin>
        <map>
          <authorizationMap>
            <authorizationEntries>
              <authorizationEntry queue=">" write="mcollective" read="mcollective" admin="mcollective" />
              <authorizationEntry topic=">" write="admins" read="admins" admin="admins" />
              <authorizationEntry topic="mcollective.>" write="mcollective" read="mcollective" admin="mcollective" />
              <authorizationEntry topic="mcollective.>" write="mcollective" read="mcollective" admin="mcollective" />
              <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="everyone" write="everyone" admin="everyone"/>
            </authorizationEntries>
          </authorizationMap>
        </map>
      </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>


    <!--
      The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
      use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:

      http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
    -->
    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <!--
      The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
      clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

      http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
    -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:6166"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613"/>
    </transportConnectors>

</broker>

<!--
  Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
  It also includes Camel (with its web console), see ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/camel.xml for more info

  Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
-->
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

activemq-wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.debug=FALSE
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_HOME=/usr/share/activemq
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_BASE=/usr/share/activemq
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_CONF=/usr/share/activemq/conf
wrapper.working.dir=/var/log/activemq

# Java Application
wrapper.java.command=java

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=/usr/share/java/tanukiwrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/bin/activemq.jar

# Uncomment to add mysql support
#wrapper.java.classpath.3=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
# Handle both 32bit and 64bit tanukiwrapper
wrapper.java.library.path.1=/usr/lib
wrapper.java.library.path.2=/usr/lib64

# Java Additional Parameters
# note that n is the parameter number starting from 1.
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dactivemq.home=%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dactivemq.base=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true

# Example configuration for SSL
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%/conf/broker.ks
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%/conf/broker.ts

#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dderby.storage.fileSyncTransactionLog=true

# Uncomment to enable jmx
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

# Uncomment to enable YourKit profiling
wrapper.java.additional.n=-Xrunyjpagent

# Uncomment to enable remote debugging
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE
#wrapper.java.additional.n=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=512
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096

# Application parameters. activemq.xml will be loaded from the config directory
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.apache.activemq.console.Main
wrapper.app.parameter.2=start
wrapper.app.parameter.3-xbean:activemq.xml

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%/log/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=7

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=ActiveMQ

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=ActiveMQ

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=ActiveMQ

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=ActiveMQ Broker

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
```

Anybody please help.
Thanks.

Comment: What memory are you talking about? Heap? Is it still high after a GC cycle?

Comment: It's system memory. It keeps on decreasing until we restart ActiveMQ.

Comment: Decrease the heap size if you want it to use less memory

Comment: Actually I want it to release memory after completing tasks. Problem is not that its using high memory at a time. Problem is it keeps on consuming memory and does not release it.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing unique about ActiveMQ - but pretty much how Java applications **can** behave. However, it **will** stay below the max memory limit, 4096 in your config. Nothing is actually wrong. Over time, the JVM **may** return some memory to the system if the java process (ActiveMQ in this case) stays low for a long period of time. The exact mechanics may differ between different JVM implementations and settings. [This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#0.0.0.%20Total%20Heap%7Coutline) explains a bit, but is a bit outdated.

Refer to this thread for some more discussion around JVM and memory management.
[java.exe process uses more memory and does not free it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649601/java-exe-process-uses-more-memory-and-does-not-free-it-up)

If you want to visualize the actual memory usage (not the memory allocated to the java process), then I suggest you connect to the ActiveMQ JVM using [jvisualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/). It's usually bundled with the JDK.