# Heap space stays constant, Javaw process shows memory leak

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, memory, memory-leaks

I am monitoring a Java app through VisualVM and I can see that the heap memory stays relatively constant, however the Java process grows larger and larger in memory.

I understand that the Java memory consists of heap memory and the JVM+PermGen memory which involves all sort of things, but my java app is a GUI application and this supposed memory leak only happens if the GUI component are in a specific configuration.

I have done some research and apparently it is possible to get memory leak while staying within the heap size. What I don't understand is how my situation could be such a scenario.

Any idea how Swing manipulations might cause such a memory leak?

Comment: Did you try to look at which part of heap causing this issue? I would say try tools like VisualVM (or) JConsole to find out the problem area, then finding solution might be easier. JConsole would be available in your JDK-->bin folder

Comment: Like I said, visualvm shows no memory leak.

Comment: Use Jconsole and check different memory allocations like permgen, old and new generations etc.,

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about JConsole. I monitored it on there. All the non-heap memories were almost constant too.

Comment: Not sure what else might be causing leak, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuned out it wasn't a memory leak after all. I was more or less in the same situation as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649601/java-exe-process-uses-more-memory-and-does-not-free-it-up).