# Why the docker container memory usage doesn't decrease?

Tags: java, docker, jvm

I'm running a Java REST app with [Apache JavaSpark](http://sparkjava.com/) in this container, but I noticed that each request is adding the memory usage and not decreasing after the request is done. My first guess was that I had forgotten to close some stream/buffer (this app deal with a lot of file manipulation), but I reviewed all the code and looks like everything is being closed.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine

WORKDIR /code

ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml

RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]

ADD src /code/src

RUN ["mvn", "package"]

EXPOSE 1337

CMD exec java -jar "target/app.jar"
```

Here is the docker stats:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
2db8b2f5fd72        0.16%               66.36 MiB / 1.952 GiB   3.32%               12.9 kB / 106 kB    0 B / 0 B           23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java usually allocates memory that has previously reserved, it only frees it when you restart the process. You can see this post that gives the full explanation.

[java.exe process uses more memory and does not free it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649601/java-exe-process-uses-more-memory-and-does-not-free-it-up)

Comment: Yeah, looks like you are right.!
I set a small memory limit for the container, so I tried to force a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, but I couldn't, when the memory usage was close to the limit it is reduced.